# Anyone having trouble reaching miktex.org?

Tags: beamer, packages, miktex

Looks like a network misconfiguration to miktex.org ....

```
  Tracing route to miktex.org [178.77.68.21]
  over a maximum of 30 hops:

    1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.28.8.2
    2    20 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.28.1.66
    3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.28.1.1
    4     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  a72-246-0-3.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com [72.246.0.3]
    5     1 ms     2 ms    <1 ms  80.67.64.193
    6     2 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  80.67.75.246
    7    30 ms    43 ms    <1 ms  bst-edge-04.inet.qwest.net [63.149.66.65]
    8     7 ms     6 ms     6 ms  jfk-brdr-04.inet.qwest.net [67.14.5.26]
    9     8 ms     6 ms     6 ms  63-235-40-58.dia.static.qwest.net [63.235.40.58]
   10    82 ms   149 ms    81 ms  po6.ar4.AMS2.gblx.net [67.17.107.174]
   11   164 ms   103 ms    82 ms  xe-1-2-0.cr-antares.ams1.hosteurope.de [206.165.75.2]
   12    89 ms   208 ms   123 ms  ae1.cr-sargas.lon1.he-core.de [80.237.129.186]
   13   191 ms    98 ms   108 ms  xe-0-1-0.cr-merak.fra2.he-core.de [80.237.129.190]
   14   104 ms   343 ms     *     xe-0-0-0.dr-master.fal1.he-core.de [176.28.4.114]
   15   317 ms   104 ms   104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   16     *      104 ms     *     pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   17   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   18   103 ms     *      103 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   19   104 ms     *      105 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   20   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   21   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   22   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   23   104 ms     *      103 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   24   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   25   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   26   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   27   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   28   105 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
   29   104 ms     *      104 ms  pvcw-5-35-228-61.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.61]
   30   104 ms     *        *     pvcw-5-35-228-2.dedicated.hosteurope.de [5.35.228.2]
```

Cannot, for example, TCP connect to grab a Beamer class using TexWorks.

*Added an hour later*

This is to speed a solution for anyone else that gets into this situation.

It turned out that for some reason the MikTeX 2.9 I was using could not get out to any repository.  I rebuilt the db, using "mpm --update-db", and reinstalled both the MikTeX binary and the TeXworks binary.  (This is on a corporate Win7 system having many security things on it.  I did check firewall issues previously.) I then tried to specify the mirror to use for package downloads.  In the MikTeX programs, there are is both an "admin" version and a non-admin version.  You want the admin one.

If you go specify that packages are to be obtained from Internet and get the list of possibilities in place of 'pick a random one', just choose a reliable one near you.

Apply and save up the choices, and you should be in business.

Comment: Same result here. After `xe-0-0-0.cr-merak.fra2.he-core.de (80.237.129.85)` I got stuck between 5.35.228.61 and 5.35.228.2

Comment: Me too but please use the chat room for such queries since this is only a matter of time to be fixed.

Comment: Need [at least 20 reputation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#what) for chat @percusse.

Comment: @texenthusiast Oh right. My bad....

Comment: The packages are anyway hosted on other site, cf. http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ – and these should also be reached by the package manager.

Comment: I think its back for me.